# Can't get access to webapp resources of child module of maven/spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I have well worked spring-boot application with structure like:
[image]

Now i trying to implement multi modules architecture with parent (pom) and two child (jar) and (war). It looks like:
[image]

But now i have 404 on loclahost:8080.
Looks like i cann't get access to child module static resources.

Parent pom:

```
...
<modules>
    <module>liquibase</module>
    <module>server</module>
</modules>

...

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

And child pom:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>stable-backend</artifactId>
     <groupId>...</groupId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>server</artifactId>

<packaging>war</packaging>
```

What's wrong with it?

**UPDATE**
I put my html to server/src/webapp/
In first case it works like a charm.
About access, i mean to get html from browser.

**UPDATE 2**
When i run spring-boot:run maven task it works as well.
The problem is produced only when i run as a spring project on intellij "run" button.

Comment: Where are the static resources located ? and how did you try to access it ?

Comment: Have you found a correct way to make it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the maven plugin to

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

to let repackage process dependent modules

Comment: Unfortunately, does not help.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late for me answering this, but you can still make it work in Intellij.

You just need to do the following:

1. Go to **Run>Edit Configurations**
2. Set your **Working directory** to the root directory of the child module. In your example, I think it should be: **`[project_directory]/stable-backend/server`**.

Note: By default, IntelliJ sets your working directory to the top level module, in your case, it is probably: **`[project_directory]/stable-backend/`**